# Can I transfer upgrades in MetalStorm to a new aircraft?

Tags: ios, metalstorm

I'm playing MetalStorm on the iPad. Having spent ages upgrading my standard plane,  I then was able to buy a new one. But the old one was better because of all the upgrades.

Is there any way to transfer the upgrades to the new plane?

Comment: Don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

tech upgrades are for the classtype of plane, not all planes or individual ones( ie weapons,defence or agility class)

So you kind of get 3 different talent tree's to build from

Comment: thanks for that, but can you please elaborate? What are the three different class types?

Answer (score -1):

Tech Upgrades is a skill tree that is used by all of your planes. So when you buy those, the new tech can be used across all planes.

But as for weapons, missiles etc. i think the answer is no. The only thing that benefits all planes are the Tech Upgrades.

[More information here](http://www.gamezebo.com/games/metalstorm-online/walkthrough).

Comment: This is not the case for me. The tech upgrades are plane specific. When I go back to the old plane, I see them all highlighted. When I view the new plane, they are not highlighted. I'm not talking about ammo or missiles.